# Laravel Azure Blob Storage Cache Images

Tags: php, laravel, image, azure, caching

this is my scenario:
I have a Laravel 6.x application and I'm using the [FlySystemAzureBlobStorage](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-azure-blob-storage) package to store images on Azure Blob Storage.
Then I want to use the [InterventionImageCache](https://github.com/Intervention/imagecache) package to get and cache the images for faster client's downloads in different sizes.
I've already done it in this way:

```
public static function getImageResponseForApi($storageDiskName, $imagePath, $width = null, $height = null)
{
    //check if the image exists on disk
    $exists = empty($storageDiskName) ?
        Storage::exists($imagePath) :
        Storage::disk($storageDiskName)->exists($imagePath);
    if ($exists) {
        $image = empty($storageDiskName) ?
            Storage::get($imagePath) :
            Storage::disk($storageDiskName)->get($imagePath);
        if (!empty($width) || !empty($height)) {
            //use the image cache function to get the cached image if exists
            $image = \Image::cache(function ($ima) use ($image, $width, $height) {
                //check if height and with are higher than original or not
                $ima->make($image)->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    $constraint->upsize();
                });
            });
        }
        $sizes = getimagesizefromstring($image);
        $headers = [
            'Content-Length' => strlen($image),
            'Content-Type' => $sizes["mime"]
        ];
        return \Response::make($image, 200, $headers);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is a problem working in this way: I must download the image from azure blob storage before the system can check if a resized cached version of it exists.

The Azure package i'm using doesn't provide the possibility to get the image paths, so I can't find another solution to my problem.

**So, is there a way to achieve the image caching without I have to download the file every time?**

Answer (score 0):

I use a separate route for showing/caching the image in my blade.
I store the image as BLOB in MYSQL PRODUCT table identified by product_id

BLADE:

```
<img src="/dbimage/{{$product->id}}.png" >
```

ROUTE:

```
Route::get('/dbimage/{id}',[ProductImageController::class, 'getImage']);
```

CONTROLLER:

```
class ProductImageController extends Controller
{

    public function getImage($prodcutImageID){
        $productID=explode(".",$prodcutImageID);
        $rendered_buffer= Product::all()->find($productID[0])->image;

        $response = Response::make($rendered_buffer);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        $response->header('Cache-Control','max-age=2592000');
        return $response;
    }

}
```

This makes the browsers cache the images